# a simple Java recursion with some kind of bug I don't get

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print (prod (1, 2));
    }
    public static int prod (int m, int n){
        if (m == 0) {
            return n+1;
        } else if(m>0 && n == 0){
            return prod (m-1, 1);
        } else if(m>0 && n >0){
            return prod(m-1,prod(m,n-1));
        }
    }
}
```

there's something wrong with:

```
public static int prod (int m, int n){
```

but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: Why do you say that "there's something wrong"? By what criteria or evidence do you feel that this is so?

Comment: There is a missing `else { return 0; }` or so.

Comment: ... and still you don't post any error messages, and still you ignore comments and requests to your question -- why?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OK, I just did't get the rules here, thanks for your notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method must return a value in all cases. You can add an additional `return` statement outside `if` statement block

```
public static int prod (int m, int n) {
   if (m == 0) {
     return n+1;
   } else if(m>0 && n == 0) {
     return prod (m-1, 1);
   } else if(m>0 && n >0) {
     return prod(m-1,prod(m,n-1));
   }

   return n;
}
```

Comment: No need for `else` keyword and curly braces if you deal with `return`.

Comment: @green_claws He means that you can simply place the return statement as the last statement in the method _outside_ the `if` statement.

Comment: @green_claws I explain my comment in an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There is no else statement at the end of the if/else chain.  What happens if m is -1?  You many know that never happens, but the compiler does not.

Answer (score 2):

You must return a value, and when your `if` conditions are all `false`, it won't.

Also, your `else` statements are redundant: if the execution of the method terminates due to an `if`, there *is no* "else".

Change your code to something like this:

```
if (m == 0)
    return n + 1;
if (m > 0 && n == 0)
    return prod(m - 1, 1);
if (m > 0 && n > 0) {
    return prod(m - 1, prod(m, n - 1));
// return a default value if no conditions met
return 0;
```

I have no idea what "prod" means, or what the intention is, so you'll have up figure out for yourself that the appropriate default value is. I chose `0` as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that natural numbers are intended.

```
public static int prod(int m, int n){
    if (m <= 0) {
        return n+1;
    } else if (n <= 0){
        return prod(m-1, 1);
    } else {
        return prod(m-1, prod(m, n-1));
    }
}
```

If with "weird" you mean termination of the recursion: that I did not see.

Answer (score 0):

Just to shorten the @Reimeus's solution: (explaining my comment above)

```
if (m == 0) 
    return n + 1;
if (m > 0 && n == 0) 
    return prod(m - 1, 1);
if (m > 0 && n > 0) 
    return prod(m - 1, prod(m, n - 1));
return n;
```

Without needing curly braces and redundant useless `else` keywords in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Thank you~!

Comment: @Bohemian Bohemian's answer has a similar way of doing.